# Please help me identify the subject and predicate in this sentence

Tags: subjects, predicate

On the top of the hill lives a hermit.
Please explain as well.

Answer (score 1):

> On the top of the hill lives a hermit.

Here the subject of the sentence (clause) is **a hermit**.

The example sentence can also be written as:

> A hermit lives on the top of the hill.

Tipically, in a sentence (clause), everything that comes after the subject or everything that is not the subject is the predicate. Consequently, the predicate in your sentence is **lives on the top of the hill**.

Comment: But, how can we tell which is the subject. Like, for instance, in this example, "The early bird catches the worm", if we change the sentence like you did, we see it from the bird's perspective. Then the bird becomes the subject. So, how can we tell which one is the subject?

Comment: @Shivam, in grammar, the subject is the doer of the action or what is described by the predicate.